# Looking for a camel-restlet sample with no Spring

Tags: apache-camel, restlet, restlet-2.0

Please help, looking for a camel-restlet sample with no Spring to expose POST rest API.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to look for examples is looking at the `Apache Camel` source code, specifically to the tests. You can find many examples and probably what you are looking for. Take a look [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=tree;f=components/camel-restlet/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/restlet).

Comment: Hi, All these examples URIs are from("restlet:http://localhost:" + portNum + "/users/ ..etc..").

Comment: Thank you, all these examples based on from("restlet:http://localhost:" + portNum + "/users/ ..etc.."). We  need to host within JBOSS container, for example  from("restlet:/enqueue?restletMethod=POST"). The same code is working with Spring [org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.spring] not without Spring [org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet].

Comment: You should update your question with more details about what is not working.